# How to use Flow Types with Mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, flowtype

I've been trying to use Flow with Mongoose (5.0.16), and so far haven't been able to figure out how to get types for my mongoose models that are actually useful. I've tried following the example [here](https://gist.github.com/nodkz/812519ca9473b28493122872ae57e9c3) but it seems to be outdated. For one, the Document type exported is `MongooseDocument`, not `Mongoose$Document`, and for another, when I try to extend `MongooseDocument`:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";
import type { MongooseDocument } from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    password: String,
    ...
  }
);

export class UserDoc extends MongooseDocument {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  ...
}

userSchema.loadClass(UserDoc);
const User = mongoose.model < UserDoc > ("User", userSchema);
export default User
```

I get the flow error `Cannot reference type MongooseDocument [1] from a value position.`
I've tried replacing `extends MongooseDocument` with `/* :: extends Mongoose$Document */` as in the example I linked above. This seemed to work, but I still have issues actually using the type.

For one thing, Flow doesn't seem sure whether `User` is a `mongoose.Model<UserDoc>` or a `UserDoc`: [image: UncertainFlow]

For another, I can't figure out what type to use for the model elsewhere. I'm trying to define a `Models` type which contains all of my models:

```
export type Models = {
  ...
  User: mongoose.Model<UserDoc>
};
```

But when I do this, I get the error: `typeof Mongoose$Document [1] is not a polymorphic type.`
If I define `Models.User` as a `UserDoc`, then it seems to just be treated as the `any` type, and I don't get any useful type inferences. `Class<UserDoc>` gives the same result.

So, what type am I supposed to use to refer to my `User` model?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be automatically pass the type into your model when you are loading class into the schema: [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdru7.png)
And here is the result: [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfGzQ.png)